# Can't get PHP to work on Apache VirtualHosting environment

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, virtualhost

Trying to setup an Apache VirtualHosting environment with PHP in a freshly created CentOS node under DigitalOcean cloud server.

The trouble is, although **Virtual hosting is working per se, PHP isn't**.

**Server Setup:**

- Web Server : CentOS 6.5 with Apache/2.2.15
- PHP Version: 5.3.3 (To be used as an Apache Module)

**Steps Taken:**

Logging in as the **root** user,

- Installing Apache and php : `yum -y install httpd php`
- Creating a new virtual host configuration file like below:

File: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.org
     ServerName example.org
     ServerAlias www.example.org
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.org/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- Creating new directories for the virtual host site

Like below,

```
mkdir -p /srv/www/example.org/public_html
mkdir -p /srv/www/example.org/logs
```

- Placing a `.php` and `.html` test files like below:

Files under `/srv/www/example.org/public_html/` (DocumentRoot)

```
echo "<HTML>It work's</HTML>"      > /srv/www/example.org/public_html/index.html
echo "<?php echo ("It works"); ?>" > /srv/www/example.org/public_html/index.php
```

Next, when I point my browser to `index.html`, it works. But when I **point my browser to `index.php` I get a blank page**.

**Troubleshooting**

(Things that I already did/checked without any luck)

- Ensured Apache is running and `DocumentRoot` is accessible
- All the directories are `755` and files `644`
- Checked Apache access log. The html page requests are there with 200 status code, but no `.php` page request present in access log
- No error in Apache or PHP error log, no error in `/var/log/messages`
- Tried adding `php_admin_flag engine on` in vhost config file

Also see below the contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `index.php` (rather than the command you used to create it)?  Testing this on the command line using `curl --include http://www.example.org/index.php` might give you a more useful error message.

Comment: @Ladadadada When I try the above `curl` command from my local machine, it returns `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: try to use php -v and give us the result of php -i | grep "configure"

Comment: What was logged in Apache's error log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Apparently Apache error log did not log any error on this. Also access log only shows access request to .html files, but not logging any access request to `.php` files

Comment: The PHP module isn't included in Apache nor PHP packages. Both are standalone. Maybe it has been included in their dependencies, that said. Have you checked if the refered files "modules/libphp5.so" or "modules/libphp5-zts.so" exists on your system ?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience PHP renders a blank page when it encounters a serious underlying error. It is usually easy to fix, but unfortunately nothing is typically logged in the Apache logs, PHP logs, or syslog making the troubleshooting process difficult.

Find your php.ini configuration file using:

```
php -i | grep "php.ini"
```

This should produce something like this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

Edit this configuration file (/etc/php.ini in this case) with your favorite text editor and be sure that displaying errors and startup errors is turned on. The entries should look like this:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Finally restart Apache so that it reads the new PHP configuration and access your page via curl or a browser. This should produce an error message that will help in the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check the Apache error logs which you have set in your Apache config; copied below:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.org
     ServerName example.org
     ServerAlias www.example.org
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.org/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

PHP runs under Apache so any errors that pop up will show up in the server logs. I recommend logging into the server & using `tail` like so:

```
tail -f -n 200 /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log
```

But is that the general Apache log for you?  Or is that DigitalOcean’s config? Because that path of `/srv/www/example.org/logs/` seems quite odd.  Under standard Linux it would be in a location like this:

```
tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Irregardless of where the logs are actually being sent, that will be the key to what is happening—or not happening—with PHP & Apache on your server.